# how to use pinia store in a vue router navigation guard?

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3, pinia

I'm using Vuejs 3, vuerouter 4 and pinia and trying to put a [navigation guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) in some routes, as per the example in the documentation (*if a user is not authenticated and is not on the login page, send the user to login page to get authenticated*). This is explained also in [pinia documentation](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/outside-component-usage.html#single-page-applications) on use of pinia outside of components. But I can't get my head around it.

The store I use is currently simple (return false or true on `isAuthenticated`):

```js
//authStore.js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useAuthStore = defineStore( 'AuthStore', {

  state: () => {
    return {
      isAuthenticated: false
    }
  }

})
```

I want to use this `isAuthenticated` in a `beforeEnter` in `routes/index.js`

In main.js:

```js
import { useAuthStore } from '@/stores/authStore'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from '@/router'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(createPinia()).use(router)
app.mount('#app')

// I'm not using authStore in this file, so this raises an error:
const authStore = useAuthStore()
```

And in router/index.js:

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

const routes = [
  // path for login page,
  {
    path: '/adm/home',
    name: 'AdmView',
    component: () => import('@/views/adm/AdmView.vue'),
    beforeEnter: (to) => {
      // error: authStore is not defined
      const isAuthenticated = authStore
      if ( !isAuthenticated && to.name !== 'login-adm' ) {
        return { name: 'login-adm' }
      }
    }
  },
  // other paths
]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `authStore.js` exports `useAuthStore` as expected, but you do not call it as required.

`authStore is not defined` because `authStore` is the filename of your auth store -- instead you should be executing the function `useAuthStore` exported from that file:

```
const authStore = useAuthStore();
console.log('Is authenticated?', authStore.isAuthenticated);
```

Answer (score -3):

I don't know if it is the main issue but u forgot to use a destructor on userStore doing

```
const isAuthenticated = authStore
```

It supposed to be

```
const { isAuthenticated } = toRefs(authStore);
```

toRefs to preserve reactivity after passing. It can be imported as

```
import { toRefs } from 'vue';
```

Comment: You're right about that, but: to maintain reactivity when destricturing in pinia, the function is `storeToRefs`, not `toRefs` which is used when destructuring `reactive` : https://pinia.vuejs.org/api/modules/pinia.html#storetorefs This is not the problem though.

Comment: U have to define userstore after importing it, thats why it is undefined